# Display office files or pdf files using ViewerJS in a Django template

Tags: javascript, html, django, pdf-viewer

I'm trying to use ViewerJS in a Django 3.1 application in order to display office documents or pdf's within a Django template.

The url I created is

http://localhost:8000/static/js/ViewerJS/index.html/#..media/files/Materials.pdf

This generates this:

[image]

That is, it lifts the index.html file but no more than that. When I look at the developer console -> networks I see that many items of viewer js are not found, I understand that this is why the presentation fails.

ViewerJS is located in static/js/ViewerJS

[image]

In the template I have tried these two ways:

`<a href="/static/js/ViewerJS/media/archivos/Materiales.pdf" class="btn">Preview</a>`

`<iframe src = "/static/js/ViewerJS/index.html/#../media/archivos/Materiales.pdf" width='700' height='550' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>`

If you know of another solution by which I can do what I need and it is not ViewerJs, it is welcome.

But neither works.

Answer (score 0):

For PDF file I use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). Just download the source in your static folder and point the pdf to the viewer.
like this:

```
<iframe src="{% static 'assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html' %}?file={{your.file.url}}" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">
```

It worked for me for pdf.
It won't work for office files.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.